# Kohana 3.1 ORM save()

Tags: controller, kohana, updating

Is there a syntactical reason that the following would not execute?

```
$final_scores = ORM::factory('fscores');
$final_scores->userid = $userid;
$final_scores->es1 = $self_awr;
$final_scores->es2 = $self_mgt;
$final_scores->es3 = $social_awr;
$final_scores->es4 = $rel_mgt;
$final_scores->save();
```

There's a model named fscores. All of the field names are correct. It's not updating the table at all.

Comment: For updating you need to select the model first.

Comment: Yes, model must be loaded before updating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments - if you want to update, load the record first:

```
$final_scores = ORM::factory('fscores', $your_id_for_update);
```

If you don't load it, save method will try to create the record:

```
public function save(Validation $validation = NULL)
{
    return $this->loaded() ? $this->update($validation) : $this->create($validation);
}
```

Also if you know you're going to update, make it expicit:

```
$final_scores->update();
```